# Python: Value of dictionary is list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

```
reclist="\"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8\",\"MOBE9J587QGMXBB7\""
print reclist
data= {
   "ids": [
      reclist #"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8","MOBE9J587QGMXBB7"
   ]
}
print data
```

Output: `

```
"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8","MOBE9J587QGMXBB7"`

{'ids': [' "MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8","MOBE9J587QGMXBB7" ']}
```

But expecting output is:

```
"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8","MOBE9J587QGMXBB7"
{'ids': ["MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8","MOBE9J587QGMXBB7"]}
```

When I print `rectlist`, it did not shows extra ' ', but when I used `reclist` in `data`, then due to extra ' ' in `reclist`, showing error `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`, as I have to add this data to `urllib2.Request`.How to strip out extra ' ' from `reclist` when used in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also `split()` and `strip()` the double quotes:

```
>>> reclist="\"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8\",\"MOBE9J587QGMXBB7\""
>>> [item.strip('"') for item in reclist.split(",")]
['MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8', 'MOBE9J587QGMXBB7']
```

Answer (score 1):

`reclist` is a string not an iterable, you can use `ast.literal_eval` in order to convert it to a tuple directly:

```
In [60]: import ast

In [61]: reclist="\"MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8\",\"MOBE9J587QGMXBB7\""

In [62]: ast.literal_eval(reclist)
Out[62]: ('MOBEEVHDBBYSQFC8', 'MOBE9J587QGMXBB7')
```